# Search form handling with Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have a search form:

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-right" data-bind="submit: findBook">
    <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" id="search-input"> 
    <i class="icon-search"></i>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm listing the books here:

```
<ul id="container" class="list" data-bind="foreach: books">
    <li>
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="center">
    <a data-bind="attr:{href: url}">            
       <img width="150" class="img-polaroid shadow" data-bind="attr:{src: image}">
    </a>
    </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
    <td class="center">
        <h6 data-bind="text: name"></h6>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And a `findBook` method in my ViewModel:

```
    self.books = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(library, function(book) { 
          return self.selectedCategory() == null ||
              book.category === self.selectedCategory(); 
          })
    });
    self.findBook = function() {
        self.books = ko.computed(function() {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(library, function(book) {
                return book.name.match(new RegExp($('#search-input').val(), 'i'));   
            });
        });
    };       
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It should filter the self.books array by name with the text you write on the form

Comment: Could you cut out those functions that aren't pertinent to the question you're asking, and include a (simplified) snippet of the HTML where you're binding the books element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `findBook` function is attempting to replace the `books` computed observable with a different one.  Your view was already bound to the previous one so you're not going to see any changes there.

You need to change your `books` computed observable to depend on some filter.  If the filter is not set, include the item.  If the filter is set, exclude it.

```
self.selectedCategory = ko.observable('');
self.nameFilter = ko.observable('');

self.books = ko.computed(function () {
    var selectedCategory = self.selectedCategory(),
        nameFilter = self.nameFilter(),
        selectedFilter = filter && new RegExp(filter, 'i');
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(library, function (book) {
        var validCategory = !selectedCategory || book.category === selectedCategory,
            validFilter = !selectedFilter || book.name.match(selectedFilter);
        return validCategory && validFilter;
    });
});

self.searchInput = ko.observable();
self.findBook = function (element) {
    self.nameFilter(self.searchInput());
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/NZmG4/)